# Define split rules in decision tree in R

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, decision-tree

I want define a specif rules for decision tree in R.

For example:

```
if a < 100 => A
else if 100 < a < 150 => B
```

Practically, define specific and personal rules for splitting data.

Thanks

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: @AndreElrico how to define specific rules in decision tree in R

Comment: @bomberdini Are you talking about interactive decision tree? So that is not possible I believe, but what you can do is use functions like `cut` or `Hmisc::cut2` to create bins for the variables and use it in a decision tree. This might help microsoft R. https://longhowlam.wordpress.com/2016/12/10/dont-give-up-on-single-trees-yet-an-interactive-tree-with-microsoft-r/